# iOS - UITableViewCell being removed from superView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell with textfileds, as soon as the cell is no longer visible on the screen I need to dismiss the keyboard. Is there a simple way to be notified when a cell is being removed from the tableView (is no longer visible)?

I tried the following in my Cell Class, and it did not get called.

```
- (void)removedFromSuperView
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cells get reused. As a cell scrolls off one end of the screen it gets reused at the other end.

Why do you need to dismiss a keyboard when the row goes off the screen? What if the user quickly scrolls the row back onto the screen? If you provide more details about what you are doing, someone can offer a more specific solution.

Comment: The cell is being reused, that's exactly why I don't want the keyboard to stay visible unless the cell is visible. What if the user starts editing indexPath [0,1], and the  the cell (textfiled, and text input) is being reused by the item at indexpath [0,20] then the change I was making is gonna be applied to [0,20], instead of [0,1]

Comment: That's only true if you are doing it wrong. I have an app with a table full of text fields. If the user is typing in one and scroll it off the screen it keeps working just fine. If the user scrolls that row back into view, it's all still there. Let the user decide when they are done. But one option is to make use of the `prepareForReuse` method of `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

Maddy is right. You need to reuse your cells, and i think it's the solution to solve your problem :

1. in your TableViewDelegate, call a method to update your cell content
2. in this method, check if the texfield "isFirstResponder"
3. if it's true, call "resignFirstResponder" in your textfield